Как вывести фрагмент строки между символами
Есть строка, например: a = "1,2,3,4,5"
Как вывести значение между запятыми (при надобности можно добавить символ или заменить)?

просто убрать ненужные символы не подходит?

Если этого было достаточно, я бы не задавал вопрос.

Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите, но возможно
print(a.split(","))


Спасибо вам огромное, все работает так как мне нужно.

Если мой ответ вам помог, то вы можете отметить его как правильный
